# How to delete rows in file under certain condition?

Tags: powershell

I've got the file 'Test.txt' which is being updated automatically. Every hour new value being added to this file. Like:

```
Some text 1:57
Some text 2:57
Some text 3:57
Some text 4:57
```

And I need to check when this file is more than 100 mb size, then delete FIRST half of the file. I mean 'Some text 1:57' and 'Some text 2:57' should be deleted in this case if the file has 4 values.
For now I have the next code where I can see the current size in KB.

```
$TestFileSize = (get-item C:\Test.txt).Length

if($TestFileSize -gt 100000){
    # --- here the code that should delete the first 50 rows if file has 100 and so on.
}
```

Any advises? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.  Here's two

```
$file = 'C:\Test.txt'
$TestFileSize = (Get-Item -Path $file).Length

if($TestFileSize -gt 100000){
    # --- here the code that should delete the first 50 rows if file has 100 and so on.
    $nlines = @([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)).Count
    (Get-Content -Path $file -Tail ([math]::Ceiling($nlines / 2))) |
    Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

or

```
$file = 'C:\Test.txt'
$TestFileSize = (Get-Item -Path $file).Length

if($TestFileSize -gt 100000){
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file
    $nlines = @($content).Count
    $content[([math]::Ceiling($nlines / 2))..($nlines -1)] | Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

Comment: thank seems like first 50% lines are deleted..but the new one are creating like this N o t h i n g   t o   u p d a t e

Comment: @SergioRamos That's an encoding issue. Append `-Encoding Default` or `UTF8` to the `Set-Content` cmdlet